# Is there a way to sync between two pouchdb instances?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I'm trying to build a topology which consists of the following:

- Two desktops connected over LAN running a native app.
- A web version of the same app.

The desktops will only have connectivity to the Internet intermittently, so both the native applications, and the web app need to have separate data stores which sync when online.

For this I found couchdb which seems to be the perfect candidate. I'm building the desktop application on Electron, so I'm thinking of using pouchdb with it and syncing it with couchdb on the server server when online.

The problem though, is that these 2 desktops running Electron apps with pouchdb will **need to sync with each other over LAN**. Does pouchdb provide the capability to sync with a remote pouchdb? I only see documentation for syncing pouch and couch.

https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html

I'm really new to the concept of synchronizing between databases. Dunno if I'm asking something obvious (or obviously impossible). Appreciate the help.

Comment: Best way to know would be to test it :) But I think that you can't sync a IndexedDB(local database created with PouchDB) remotely. One solution would be to have a CouchDB installed with each application.

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_over_http Make sure to check the section about PouchDB Server

Comment: @Phonolog isn't this like a replacement for couchdb itself? You're saying I could run a pouchdb server inside the Electron app? And make calls from my app to the pouchdb server? I did check this page before posting the question, but didn't look into it coz it looked like an implementation of the couch protocol that's supposed to sit server side and sync with the embedded pouchdb that's sitting client side over the net. I didn't really find any information to embed the pouchdb server into an electron app.

Comment: @Alexis The thing is I don't even know how to even try to access a pouchdb instance from another pouchdb. Couchdb exposes itself as an HTTP resource, so it's straightforward to connect pouchdb with that. And about packaging the couchdb directly inside my application, yeah that would be an answer, but I haven't found a way to package it (or even have it interact with) an electron app. Some more detail on how I would get those two to talk to each other directly would be totally helpful.

Comment: @alokraop What you're trying to do seems like Peer-to-Peer. This might help : https://github.com/natevw/PeerPouch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sync p2p over arbitrary data channels, you may want to look at this plugin: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream

In your case, though, since you're writing a native app, the dead-easiest way to do this is to use express-pouchdb to sync between the two desktop apps. Here is a video showing how this can be done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iTzm8sTtd4

Any two `PouchDB` objects can sync with one another; so as long as you have working `PouchDB` objects you can sync them with `db1.sync(db2)`.

Comment: Oh this looks like it's exactly what I wanted. Will check it out. Thanks a lot :-D